# Elasticsearch Filter Dynamically Aggregated Fields

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to serach/filter results based on front-end selections in available acategories:

I am able to get data in hits, and aggreagation as well, which gives me all available productCategory, Color and Brand.

Now when someone selects a brand, I want to be able to send that variable to my backend via UriParams

```
'example.com/search?productBrand=Apple'
```

Now, for one filter, I am able to do it, and more but what if an user selects 1 Brand Filter, 2 Colors and 3 Product Categories.
How am I able to do that in my back end?

This is my body object that I am sending via Axios using elastic-js

```
body: {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "mainCategory.v.keyword": "HaSoftrdware"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "cObj.n.keyword": [
              "Apple",
              "Microsoft"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
    },
    "from": from,
    "size": 6,
    "sort": [
      {
        "price": {
          "order": "asc"
        }
      }
    ],
    "aggs": {
      "mainCategory": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "mainCategory.n.keyword",
        }
      },
      "city": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "cObj.n.keyword",
        }
      },
      "make": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "carMake.n.keyword",
        }
      },
      "model": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "carModel.n.keyword",
        }
      },
      "gasoline": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "carGasoline.n.keyword",
        }
      },
      "adType": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "adType.keyword",
        }
      },
      "carTable": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "carTable.n.keyword",
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Do I need to pre-define everything in my back-end or how is it archived.. this is getting over my head last 2-3 days I am struggling

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you can have querying engine (with visitors design patterns) that will generate proper query body that you need for searching. Also Elastic clients in different languages can be used to achieve what you want. you can find elastic node.js client documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/index.html).